# htaccess domain access without file endings

Tags: .htaccess

I want domain.de/test.php to appear without the .php.
I tried this, but its not working. Is there a conflict maybe?

This is my full .htaccess now. Do I have an error somewhere or conflict?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]

# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bm-translations.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

<IfModule mod_filter.c>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
## Enable gzip compression ##
# compress text, HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and XML
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Remove browser bugs
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
## END Enable gzip compression ##
</IfModule>
</IfModule>

AddType font/woff .woff
ExpiresByType font/woff "access plus 1 year"
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff

AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 3 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 3 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 3 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I tried to put the part with file-extension on top and at the bottom, but everywhere its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to add `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://bm-translations.de/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#remove the need for .php extention 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www and redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

# internally add .php extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: now all subdomains arent accessable anymore and are either redirected to domain oder give a 404 error. I updated my question and posted full htaccess.

Comment: I still need all answers to my questions to understand your problem.  What are full URLs giving errors and what is **exact error** you're getting?

Comment: some subpages have 404 error. others are redirected to homepage instead just removing file ending. I cant see a structure in this.

Comment: You're still not answering my question that I have asked twice and without that there is no help possible.

Comment: there is no error in console. 
Example: I want to go to domain.de/test >>>  404 error
Example: I want to go to domain.de/test123 >>>  redirect domain.de

Comment: See updated answer. Keep only this code in your .htaccess and test with this this URL **after clearing browser cache** `https://domain.de/test`. Assuming `test.php` exists in your site root directory.

Comment: I tried with only your code, but getting 404 for every subpage I am trying.

Comment: This is a working rule on my live website so it has to be some local config/code issue for you. Unfortunately you haven't provided any concrete tracing info to find the problem on your site.